# having problems using iterators with lists in c++

Tags: c++, list, multidimensional-array, iterator

I am writing an algorithm that checks for duplicate moves in checker in c++ but I am having problems with using the `iterator`.

Here is my code:

```
static std::list<char[8][8]> duplicates;   

    char checkForDuplicates[8][8];
    for(char i = 0;i < 8;i++)
        for(char j = 0;j < 8;j++)
            checkForDuplicates[i][j] = board[i][j];
    bool isDuplicate = false;
    for(std::list<char[8][8]>::iterator it = duplicates.begin(); it != duplicates.end(); it++)
    {
        for(char i = 0;i < 8;i++)
        {
            for(char j = 0;j < 8;j++)
            {
                if(checkForDuplicates[i][j] != it->[i][j])
                    //do something
            }
        }
    }
```

I especially need help with this line:

```
if(checkForDuplicates[i][j] != it->[i][j])
```

I am trying to compare an array element in the list to another array element but I have no idea how to access the array elements inside the list using the `list iterator`. Can anybody please assist me with examples and/or advice?

Comment: I don't think you can store an array inside a `std::list`, since array types aren't copy constructible or assignable, two requirements necessary to store a type in an STL container.  Perhaps they relaxed this in C++11, though.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `it->[i][j]` use `(*it)[i][j]`. The `->` notation is only used when you're accessing a member, but your list contains arrays, not classes or structs.

Answer (score 1):

It may may things easier to understand if you create a reference to the object from the iterator.  After that, you can access it how you normally would.

```
static std::list<char[8][8]> duplicates;   

    char checkForDuplicates[8][8];
    for(char i = 0;i < 8;i++)
        for(char j = 0;j < 8;j++)
            checkForDuplicates[i][j] = board[i][j];
    bool isDuplicate = false;
    for(std::list<char[8][8]>::iterator it = duplicates.begin(); it != duplicates.end(); it++)
    {
        char (&thisBoard)[8][8] = *it;  # <--
        for(char i = 0;i < 8;i++)
        {
            for(char j = 0;j < 8;j++)
            {
                if(checkForDuplicates[i][j] != thisBoard[i][j])
                    //do something
            }
        }
    }
```